# If anonymous object use the local variable of external method infinity, it can be stack overflow or not?

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous

I have a question about anonymous object in Java.

If I make a static method(`name = go()`) which has one anonymous object and this anonymous object uses the local variable of `go()`.

I know that local variable which is used for anonymous object has to be declared to be `final`.

And then `final variable(numberCnt)` is made in stack area instead of heap area.

The stack area is not target of GC.

if I call `go()` infinitely, will stack overflow occur or not?

The below is my question source.

```java
package com;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i =0;

        while(true) {
            i++;
            go(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if(i > 10_000_000) {
                i=0;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void go(int i) {

        int numberCnt = i;

        Callable<String> callable = new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                String rtnValue = "Number=>" + numberCnt;

                System.out.println("Number=>" + rtnValue);

                return rtnValue;
            };
        };

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        executorService.submit(callable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous class copies the value of the variables it captures at the moment the anonymous class object is created. So basically your anonymous class has a hidden `int` instance variable for its capture of `numberCnt`, and you can imagine, behind the scenes, the compiler basically passes `numberCnt` into the hidden "constructor" of your anonymous class to initialize this hidden instance variable. The stack frame of `go` is gone when the function returns, and there is never more than 1 stack frame for `go` on the stack. You just get lots of instances of your anonymous class on the heap, and each of those instances has an `int` instance variable with a different value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
You mean that I don't need to worry about Stack over flow because anonymous object will be removed after used in the go().
Right??

Comment: @Thecaptinofsixcanon: The object is referenced by the executor, and will be garbage collected after the executor executes it.